# Sort result by date difference

Tags: solr

We have a solr result queried by a date range +/- 1 Month of the date entered. If i entered 2012-12-01 i get a Result Set from 2012-11-01 to 2013-01-01.

This works fine, but we want to sort the Result after the date difference to the date entered.

For example if we have the Dates:

> 2012-11-10, 2012-11-30, 2012-12-03, 2012-12-10

we want the Result sorted like this:

> 2012-11-30, 2012-12-03, 2012-12-10, 2012-11-10

Any Ideas how to accomplish this in solr?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can just add `&sort=sub(date_you_enter,date_fieldname_on_documents) asc` parameter to your query. basically `sub` function will calculate the difference and then you will be able to sort it depending on that result.

for reference you can also check http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery page for more functions that could be useful for you

Comment: Thanks, i found this but was unable to get it working and now i know why... solr 1.4^^ need upgrading first.

Comment: finally i used the ms function for the problem:

&sort=abs(ms(date_you_enter,date_fieldname_on_documents)) asc

ms returns the difference in milliseconds, abs returns the leading sign