# Solr combine date fields in sorting

Tags: sorting, solr

We have some documents which are indexed with a date `d1` on some of the documents and `d2` on others, and we want to sort on both of them depending which one os available.

```
sort=d1 desc, d2 desc
```

will sort the document with `d1` seperatly for the document with `d2`, like this:

```
d1: 2014-03-12
d1: 2010-03-12
d2: 2013-03-12
d2: 2011-03-12
```

What we want is everything sorted like this:

```
d1: 2014-03-12
d2: 2013-03-12
d2: 2011-03-12
d1: 2010-03-12
```

Reindexing all documents with a new common field is not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

The approach of Abdul to use a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018214/solr-combine-date-fields-in-sorting/33211826#33211826) is the correct approach.
But the solution of Abdul does not work for me.

I've successfully tested this.

Just add this parameter to your query:

```
sort=max(d1,d2) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

As much i know, you can use Function Queries of solr. For this sort, it is something like that

sort=if((abs(ms(d1,d2)) > 0),d1,d2) desc

I have not tested it yet, but here is the helpful link which will sort out your problem.

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery 
[Sort result by date difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366620/sort-result-by-date-difference)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a copyField from d1 and d2 to dAll and then sort on dAll ?

You can check copyField informations here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields

Answer (score 0):

As it was invoqued in [this discussion](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Concat-2-fields-in-another-field-td4086786.html), you can update your data with [ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html) by trying something like:

```xml
<processor class="com.test.solr.update.CustomConcatFieldUpdateprocessorFactory">
  <str name="field">d1</str>
  <str name="field">d2</str>
  <str name="dest">date</str>
  <str name="delimiter"></str>
</processor>
```

After that, you can try to sort by your field date.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions, one of which has already been proposed:
(1) Use [`copyField`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields).

```
<field name="d" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>    
<copyField source="d1" dest="d" />
<copyField source="d2" dest="d" />
```

Even if the `d1` and `d2` fields are important, you can still include them in your query, but just sort on the merged `d` field.

(2) Depending upon the type of your data source, you could potentially modify the query in your `data-config.xml` file to merge these two fields into one.  In our environment, we are using Solr to index data from a MySQL instance.  There are many times where data from different databases is being consolidated into Solr.  This introduces a similar problem where we need to normalize data that is coming from different databases.  In these situations, we often use constructs like `CASE` or `IFNULL` in our queries.  I can get into more specifics if this is applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem very similar to yours. In my case all documents had the "d1" and "d2" fields, and all of them had the "d1" value. The "d2" value is used to overwrite the "d1" value.

My solution for this is:

```
sort=map(ms(d2),0,0,ms(d1)) desc
```

The `map(ms(d2),0,0,ms(d1))` will return the "d2" timestamp if it is not empty; if it is, the "d1" timestamp is used instead

Hope it helps someone.